# Codeigniter session not saving data

Tags: codeigniter, session, paypal

as title said I'm working with codeigniter (v2.X) and I'm including [angelleye's Paypal library](https://www.angelleye.com/product/codeigniter-paypal-integration-express-checkout-basic-demo/). It was pretty hard to understand at first but I manage to make recurring payments.
Now I'm facing an other issue relative to that. I need to generate shopping cart array for SetExpressCheckout() and save it into a user's data session to use it after user log into paypal account. 
Here goes some code

```
private function _setPaypalPayment($data)
{

    $cart['items'][0] = array(
        'id' => '1',
        'name' => "Payment ",
        'qty' => '1',
        'price' => (float)$data->money,
    );

    $cart['shopping_cart'] = array(
        'items' => $cart['items'],
        'subtotal' => (float)$data->money,
        'shipping' => 0,
        'handling' => 0,
        'tax' => 0,
    );

    $cart['shopping_cart']['grand_total'] = (float)$data->money;
    $this->session->set_userdata('shopping_cart', $cart);

    $SECFields = array(
        'maxamt' => (float)$data->money,
        'returnurl' => site_url('payment/confirmTrackPayment'),
        'cancelurl' => 'http://xxx',
        'hdrimg' => 'http://xxx/assets/images/logo_750X90.png',
        'logoimg' => 'http://xxx/assets/images/logo_190X60.png',
        'brandname' => 'xxx',
        'surveyquestion' => '',
        'customerservicenumber' => '',
    );

    $Payments = array();
    $Payment = array(
        'amt' => (float)$data->money,
    );

    array_push($Payments, $Payment);

    $PayPalRequestData = array(
        'SECFields' => $SECFields,
        'Payments' => $Payments,
    );

    $PayPalResult = $this->paypal_pro->SetExpressCheckout($PayPalRequestData);

    if(!$this->paypal_pro->APICallSuccessful($PayPalResult['ACK']))
    {
        return null;
    }
    else
    {
        return $PayPalResult['REDIRECTURL'];
    }
}
```

This part is working just fine, it return the URL and the user can log into his account. But when he return into payment/confirmTrackPayment and I make

```
$cart = $this->session->userdata('shopping_cart');
```

or

```
$all = $this->session->all_userdata();
```

The info of shopping_cart is not there. I can't find any answer for these, please help me!

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

I'm not certain (I have no experience with Angeleyes) but I had a look at the code in the github repo and I think you need to set the shopping_cart like this (I also tidied it up a bit) :-

```
$items = array(
    array(
        'id' => '1',
        'name' => "Payment ",
        'qty' => '1',
        'price' => (float)$data->money,
    ),
);

$cart = array(
    'items' => $items,
    'subtotal' => (float)$data->money,
    'shipping' => 0,
    'handling' => 0,
    'tax' => 0,
    'grand_total' => (float)$data->money,
);

$this->session->set_userdata('shopping_cart', $cart);
```

Comment: Thanks, that's almost the same as the code I made. But the problem is not with the payment, the problem is with session's userdata. It's not saving the info. If I retrieve the info just after the set_userdata() the info is there, but after the user goes inside his paypal account and come back to the specify return url, the info inside userdata is not there

Comment: There's a few reasons why your session data would be missing - 1. session_start() was not called before setting the session data. 2. session_start() was not called before getting the session data. 3. session_start() was called after something was output to the browser. 4. The redirect went to a different domain (perhaps a subdomain). 5. PHP can not write to your tmp directory. Perhaps try looking in your error logs.

Comment: I'll go with 4, but In Angeleyes he redirect to a different domain (paypal domain), so how can i do to save the data before redirect to another domain and the came back?

Comment: Sorry, I meant that when the user is redirected back to your site from paypal, they land on a different domain then the one they started on.

Comment: Same domain, no main changes. 'returnurl' => site_url('payment/confirmTrackPayment')

Comment: So we can rule out number 4. Perhaps check the source of 'payment/confirmTrackPayment' in the Chrome web inspector and see if any errors are output at the top of the page? Beyond that, you really need to turn error logging on and have a look at the log file after doing a test.

Comment: error log is on, and the 'payment/confirmTrackPayment' is a simple print_r so I can see if the data is there. Really weird